# Gravity forms: show review page based on value radiobutton

Tags: gravityforms

I use this script for displaying a review page before submit: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/gravity-forms/gravity-forms-how-to-add-pre-submission-review-page/

It works, but I just need to display the review page when the value of a rdaiobutton is Yes.
i have this, but it doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'gform_review_page_19', 'add_review_page_ccm', 10, 3 );
function add_review_page_ccm( $review_page, $form, $entry ) {
$review_page['is_enabled'] = true;
$review_page['content'] .= GFCommon::replace_variables( '{all_fields}', $form, $entry );
$selected_radio = rgar( $entry, '8' );
if ( $selected_radio == 'Yes' ){ 
                                return $review_page;
                }  
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't have a code solution for you but this is easily achievable with Preview Submission (https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-preview-submission/) as the review page is represented as an HTML field on the form and you can use Gravity Forms conditional logic to show or hide that page based on your condition.

Comment: Thanks Dave, if this doesn't work I have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 add_filter( 'gform_review_page', 'add_review_page_ccm', 10, 3 );
 function add_review_page_ccm( $review_page, $form, $entry ) {
    if ( $entry['8'] == 'Yes' && $form['id'] == 19){//change 19 to your form id 
       $review_page['is_enabled'] = true;
       $review_page['content'] .= GFCommon::replace_variables( '{all_fields}', $form, $entry );
    }
    return $review_page;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rochelle,

Thanks for your answer. I have tried this, but it doesn't work: the form is submitted instead of going to the review page.  Is there something I can try?